# ubuntu 22.04 on Dell Poweredge T310

Tags: server, software-installation, 22.04, dell

I have a Dell Poweredge T310.  Ubuntu hasn't been certified to work on this server.  I have updated the bios and firmware, but still I get an error while installing Ubuntu.  I was able to install 22.04 on a T110II with no problem.  I want to use this server to learn Linux.  Has anyone figured out this puzzle and can provide a solution?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Are you installing the OS onto a RAID array, or straight on a single disk?

Comment: "an error" isn't a lot to go on. Please provide more details about the errors you're seeing.